# Character issues with emulator's SQL Server CE

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I am developing a pocket pc application by PP Emulator in .Net. There is a problem that I don't understand in SQL Server CE. I can't type turkish characters in SQL Server CE query analyzer and also if my query has a value with turkish characters, it raises format exception. How can I solve that problem? I am using Vs 2008 and SQL Server CE 3.5 SP1. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it only the query analyzer that fails? Or does your application also fail? Did you use NVARCHAR or NCHAR data types to store your unicode text?